# How to sliding up div container , which the div container one below another after collapse the first div container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, grid

I am having two div container like one below another , after collapsing the first div container the below container should move up.In this scenario i am not able to move the below container to up.How to do this ?

```
<!-- here is 1st conatiner  -->
<section id="widget-template" class="widget grid-stack-item grid-stack-item-content">
      <header>
               <h5><span class="widget_name fw-semi-bold">Widget</span></h5>
               <div class="widget-controls" style="width: 200px;">

                  <a data-widgster="expand" title="Expand" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="widgetExpand(this)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></a>
                  <a data-widgster="collapse" title="Collapse" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="widgetCollapse(this)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></a>

               </div>
           </header>
           <div class="widget-body" style="margin-left: auto;top: 9%;">!-- here is my chart  --></div>
           <
      </section>

 <!-- here is 2nd conatiner  -->

<section id="widget-template" class="widget grid-stack-item grid-stack-item-content">
      <header>
               <h5><span class="widget_name fw-semi-bold">Widget</span></h5>
               <div class="widget-controls" style="width: 200px;">

                  <a data-widgster="expand" title="Expand" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="widgetExpand(this)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></a>
                  <a data-widgster="collapse" title="Collapse" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="widgetCollapse(this)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></a>

               </div>
           </header>
           <div class="widget-body" style="margin-left: auto;top: 9%;">  <!-- here is my chart  --></div>

      </section>
```

I am having collapse button for both container, after collapsed first container the second container should move up.

Comment: please provide Your code then only we can help You

Comment: Can u add code snippet here?

Comment: @Abi, i added code Abi.